# Adding metadata for films/TV shows in iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows, metadata

When I purchase videos from iTunes, I get a lot of metadata information on the movie. For example, like this:

[image]

But when I add a DVD I own, I only get this:

[image]

I understand that on OSX you can use [Subler](https://code.google.com/p/subler/) to add iTunes metadata for videos, but how can I do this in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any program that can tag MP4s should work fine. [MetaX](http://www.danhinsley.com) seems to be a popular one for Windows that can pull data from various online databases.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by editing the metadata in iTunes itself. Select a video, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> then edit the data.

Comment: Needless to say, the answer is definitively "no".